# ImportError: cannot import name 'QOpenGLWidget'

Tags: python, pyqt5

ubuntu 14.04 python3.4
I installed Qt long time ago
and I use this command to install the QT5 library

```
sudo apt-get install qt-sdk
```

And I checked the version of Qt by

```
qmake -v
```

and it is:

```
 QMake version 3.0 
 Using Qt version 5.2.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Then I installed SIP 4.16.3
and checked it both in Terminal and python3, 4.16.3

Then I installed PyQt5.3.2

```
tar -zxvf PyQt-gpl-5.3.2.tar.gz
cd PyQt-gpl-5.3.2
python3 configure.py  
sudo make 
sudo make install
```

In python3 it can import PyQt5 and almost modules but the QOpenGLWidget

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'QOpenGLWidget'
```

In PyCharm:
[image]

I dont know how to solve the ImportError error problem...
Any advice will be thanksful:)

Comment: Are you sure that the python that uses pycharm is the same one that you used to compile pyqt?

Comment: also if you have installed Qt 5.2.1 you must install PyQt5 5.2.1

Comment: Thank you for your advice. My python in Pycharm and in Terminal is the same. And I reinstall the pyqt5.2.1 but the same import error. I think this version is too low to contain the 'QOpenGLWidget' module. So I reinstall the QT5.7.0 and pyqt5.7.0 and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I think this version is too low to contain the 'QOpenGLWidget' module. So I reinstall the QT5.7.0 and pyqt5.7.0 and everything works.